# Android recyclerview inside another recyclerview with checkbox

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview inside another recyclerview with multiple checkbox. I had create two sepreate Adapter for both recyclerviews. Child of first recyclerview have checkbox. When i clicked on first block of recyclerview then 2nd block check must unchecked. Sharing 3 images for better understanding.
[image: Image one] [image: Image 2][image]

Android inside second adapter I have add this code to remove checkbox

```
holder.check_select.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            try {
                if (ids.size() == 0) {
                    String id = allOrders.get(position).getOrder_id();
                    if (isChecked) {
                        ids.add(id);
                    } else {
                        ids.clear();
                    }
                } else {
                    String id = allOrders.get(position).getOrder_id();
                    for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
                        String ordId = ids.get(i);
                        if (id.equalsIgnoreCase(ordId)) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                ids.add(id);
                            } else {
                                //removeAllMark(holder.check_select);
                                holder.check_select.setChecked(false);
                                ids.remove(i);
                            }
                            break;
                        } else {
                            holder.check_select.setChecked(false);
                            ids.clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
                getPerspective().showErrorLog("Adapter", "Ids Size : " + ids.size());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Please help to find the solution

Comment: Currently with your implementation what is the behaviour of selection

Comment: Not get your point for -"what is the behaviour of selection"

Comment: I mean you presented with your images how the functionality should be. But you have already implemented some code rite, what is the issue you are facing like one item is getting selected or exactly what is happening with item selection with your current implementation.